Limit behavior root of equation
Problem :
Let $f$ be a function which has positive-second derivative and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.
For arbitrary positive real number $k$, $p$ and $q$ denotes root of $f(x) = k$ ($p<q$).
Prove/disprove that
$$\lim_{k\to 0+} \frac{q}{p} = -1$$

My Attempt :
At first, I tried to taylor theorem :
$$\frac{k}{q^2} = \frac{f(q)}{q^2} = \frac{f''(c)}{2}\quad (0<c<q) \\ \frac{k}{p^2} = \frac{f(p)}{p^2}=\frac{f''(d)}{2}\quad (p<d<0)$$
and
$$\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^2 = \frac{f''(d)}{f''(c)}$$
now let $k\to 0+$ then $f''(d) \to f''(0)$, $f''(c) \to f''(0)$.
But this method have two problems :

What if $f''(x)$ has no limit to $0$?
Can I deduce that $\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^2 \to 1 \Longrightarrow \frac{q}{p}\to -1$?

Thanks for help

Apply the Peano form of the remainder. Then you get $${k\over q^2}={f''(0)\over 2}+ r_1(q)$$ $${k\over p^2}={f''(0)\over 2}+ r_2(p)$$ where $r_1(q),$ $ r_2(p)$ tend to $0$ when $q\to 0^+,\ p\to 0^-,$ respectively. Concerning $2.$ we have $p/q<0.$
